# Attempting to start a tween returns a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

First off since that's my first post, hail to everyone in this community. I already found a ton of information that helped me tackle the problems i encountered so far. Now i ran into a problem I am unable to solve. I am making a "Pang" type of game, probably some of you have seen or played some sort of variation. So to the point. I am currently trying to make an object, linked to a class, bounce on the stage. I decided to try and use easeIn and easeOut tweens.

I declare the tweens inside the main document class:

```
public static var upTween:Tween;
    public static var downTween:Tween;
```

and use a for loop to assign their value to all objects part of an array:

```
public function bounce(event:Event):void
    {
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < bubbles1.length; i++)
        {
            upTween = new Tween(bubbles1[i], "y", Strong.easeOut, bubbles1[i].y, 250, 2, true);
            downTween = new Tween(bubbles1[i], "y", Strong.easeIn, bubbles1[i].y, stage.stageHeight - 50 - bubbles1[i].height, 2, true);
        }
    }
```

Now when i try to start the tweens from inside the Bubble.as class i get a null object reference.

Perhaps a little bit more info that would be helpful. I am instantiating the object in a public function from within the main class as follows:

```
public function makeBubble(size:Number, xCoordinate:Number, yCoordinate:Number, xDir:Number):void
        {
            if (size == 1)
            {
            bubble = new Bubble(stage);
            bubble.x = xCoordinate;
            bubble.y = yCoordinate;
            bubble.xDirection = xDir;
            bubbles1.push(bubble);
            stage.addChild(bubble);

            }
```

Here is the full Bubble.as class:

```
package com.zdravko.pong
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;



public class Bubble extends MovieClip
{
    private var stageRef:Stage;

    var xDirection:Number;
    var yDirection:Number;

    var bubble2:Bubble2;




    public function Bubble(stageRef:Stage) 
    {
        // constructor code
        this.stageRef = stageRef;


        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

    }

    function loop(event:Event):void
    {
        if(this.x >= stage.stageWidth - this.width)
        {
            this.x = stage.stageWidth - this.width - 5;
            xDirection *= -1;
        }
        if(this.x <= 0)
        {
            this.x = 5;
            xDirection *= -1;
        }
        if(this.y >= stage.stageHeight - 50 - this.height)
        {               
            this.y = stage.stageHeight - 50 - this.height;
            Engine.upTween.start();
        }
        if(this.y <= 250)
        {
            this.y = 250;
            Engine.downTween.start();

        }

        this.x += xDirection;


        if(hitTestObject(Engine.player) && Player.invul == false)
           {
               decreaseEnergy(.4);
               Player.invul = true;
               Player.invulTimer.start();
           }
    }

    public function decreaseEnergy(dmg:Number):void
    {
        Engine.energy.scaleX -= dmg;
    }

    public function takeHit() : void
    {

        makeBubble(2, this.x + 50, this.y + 30, 8, 8);
        makeBubble(2, this.x - 20, this.y - 30, -8, 8);
        removeSelf();
        Engine.playerScore += 500;
        Engine.score.scoreBox.text = Engine.playerScore;
    }

    private function removeSelf() : void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

        if (stageRef.contains(this))
        {
            stageRef.removeChild(this);
        }
    }

    private function makeBubble(size:Number, xCoordinate:Number, yCoordinate:Number, xDir:Number, yDir:Number):void
    {

        bubble2 = new Bubble2(stage);
        bubble2.x = xCoordinate;
        bubble2.y = yCoordinate;
        bubble2.xDirection = xDir;
        bubble2.yDirection = yDir;
        Engine.bubbles2.push(bubble2);
        stageRef.addChild(bubble2);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hmm. Why "for" cycle that operates with static variables? You see, in case you'd have 20 bubbles, you will need 40 tween objects, and you only have 2. Perhaps what you observe is an architecture error, not located in this particular place.

Comment: I am quite sure there is a better way to do this, I just wasn't able to think of one. The error i get is Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. If i remove the Engine.upTween.start(); line from the Bubble.as class, the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the bubbles array is returning a null value. Have you tried tracing out the values from the bubbles1 array.

```
public function bounce(event:Event):void
{
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < bubbles1.length; i++)
    {
       // log out the value from your array
       trace("bubble " + bubbles1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just did that, on the line where i try to start the tween added trace(Engine.bubbles1.length); and it did return 1 as it should.

Comment: Okay. I would recommend tracing the values in the array rather than the length to check that the value is not a null

Comment: tryed, what you suggested after edditing. same result :(

Comment: At what point is { public function bounce(event:Event):void } getting called

Comment: It receives an enter_frame event from the main class constructor

Comment: Post your bubbles.as class as I think there may be an issue there

Comment: Editted the thread with the full content of the Bubble.as class. Hope this helps you help me :)